# Can't build SceneBuild from openjfx source code and setup

Tags: java, ant, javafx

I'm trying to build JavaFX sceneBuilder on my laptop I've dowloaded the source code from OpenJFx project and successfully build the SDK but during scene builder build i've got the following error, I'm a little bit confused since I'm completely digiune of gradle i don't understand where i should put the required property, in which folder or which configuration file i should modify, and why grade is running ant tasks, I've not ant installed on my machine (it's not in the prerequisite
of the openjfx wiki).

Many thanks

```
Galileo openjfx $ gradle sceneBuilderAppJar
:buildSrc:generateGrammarSource UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
MACOSX_MIN_VERSION = 10.7
MACOSX_SDK_PATH = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
OS_NAME: mac os x
OS_ARCH: x86_64
JAVA_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
JDK_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
java.runtime.version: 1.8.0_40-b27
java version: 1.8.0_40
java build number: 27
jdk.runtime.version: 1.8.0_40-b27
jdk version: 1.8.0_40
jdk build number: 27
minimum java build number: 132
CONF: Debug
NUM_COMPILE_THREADS: 1
COMPILE_TARGETS: mac
COMPILE_FLAGS_FILES: buildSrc/mac.gradle
HUDSON_JOB_NAME: not_hudson
HUDSON_BUILD_NUMBER: 0000
PROMOTED_BUILD_NUMBER: 00
PRODUCT_NAME: OpenJFX
RAW_VERSION: 8.0.60
RELEASE_NAME: 8u60
RELEASE_MILESTONE: ea
UPDATE_STUB_CACHE: false
The CompileOptions.useAnt property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. There is no replacement for this property.
:apps:scenebuilderAppJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':apps:scenebuilderAppJar'.
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /Users/fabiofrumento/openjfx/apps/scenebuilder/build.xml:19: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /Users/fabiofrumento/openjfx/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderKit/nbproject/build-impl.xml:86: The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.
   Your active platform is: JDK_1.8, but the corresponding property "platforms.JDK_1.8.home" is not found in the project's properties files.
   Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
   For example like this:
       ant -Duser.properties.file=<path_to_property_file> jar (where you put the property "platforms.JDK_1.8.home" in a .properties file)
    or ant -Dplatforms.JDK_1.8.home=<path_to_JDK_home> jar (where no properties file is used)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.228 secs
Galileo openjfx $
```

Comment: Why to take all the pain when you can download the [scene builder builds from GluonHQ](http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/) ;)

Comment: Why to use opensource if all you want is a packaged product ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I can't upvote your comment enough. Saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

The problem was the gradle build system don't set the platforms.JDK_1.8.home I've solved this way:

```
1) Installed latest ant from apache official site

2) Gone into the apps/scenebuilder folder

3) Run ant -Dplatforms.JDK_1.8.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/ jar
```

This worked for me, the result of the build is in the "dist" folder and to run the just built scene builder i had to use

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java -cp /Users/fabiofrumento/openjfx/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderKit/dist/SceneBuilderKit.jar:/Users/fabiofrumento/openjfx/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderApp/dist/SceneBuilderApp.jar com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp
```

Obviously the paths are to be customized for you installation.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow currently I'm out of office